# Compute cell values and isosurface constant from density values of particles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, visualization

I am trying to reconstruct the surface for a fluid simulation based on a list of particles using the Marching Cubes algorithm. From different resources, such as http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/, or https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp16/cse169-a/slides/CSE169_15.pdf

I see that I have to compute an isosurface based on a 3D scalar field. My question is, how can I set density values to the corners of the cubes for each cell of the grid and how should I compute the isosurface constant. Is that constant same for every cell, or unique for each one?

Comment: Usually you would either define the fluid quantities in the cell centers or on the faces, depending on the scheme. After that, it should be simple interpolation to get the values at the corners.

Comment: As a problem of fluid dynamics, i would also be happy if someone could give me a step by step theoretical approach

Comment: @PetrosYannopoulos What problem did you solve and in what language is the code written?